# Symfony differentiating similar routes with requirements

Tags: php, symfony

I have these 2 similar routes on different actions:

```
@Route("/profile/{username}/{submenu}", requirements={"submenu"="^(?!edit)$"})

@Route("/profile/{username}/edit", name="profileEdit")
```

however it seems whenever i go to the edit url, im redirected to the first route. Could someone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Put your `edit` route before the other in your controller.

Comment: And if I want 2 separate controllers?

Comment: I you don't have specific needs I would change the approach adding `@Route("/profile/{username}/{submenu}/something"` or `@Route("/profile/{username}/{submenu}-something"` to the route. This will avoid any problem/conflicy.

Comment: You can also differentiate the route actions assigning a different method to specific route actions like using a "PATCH" method for `edit` the `username` like: `@Route("/profile/{username}"`, `@Method({"PATCH"})`.

Comment: @user1009698 you may place both routes in routing.yml with `edit` for first. Otherwise try to set `requirements={"submenu": "^(?!edit$).*"}`.